# airflow 09:43:23.50 ERROR ==> Could not connect to the database - while installing airflow through bitnami helm chart

Tags: python, airflow, kubernetes-helm, bitnami, requirements.txt

I Installed Airflow through bitnami helm chart with the below version

> CHART NAME: airflow
>
> CHART VERSION: 12.5.8
>
> APP VERSION: 2.3.2

and I replace bitnami image with my customized image for airflow webserver, scheduler and worker which include python library and other `apt-get` packages.

When I pull customized image it will through the below error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

We've faced a similar issue.

When using our custom image, the airflow component (scheduler in our case) is missing the recommended Postgres driver: psycopg2.

not sure why, and how it works with bitnami image.

bitnami helm chart uses this recommended driver:
`postgresql+psycopg2://<user>:<password>@<host>/<db>`.

(from official airflow documentation: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/set-up-database.html#setting-up-a-postgresql-database).

Therefore, what worked for us was just to **add this python package (psycopg2) to the requirements.txt and build a new version**.

We used `psycopg2-binary==2.9.3` for dev.